# Find the parametric equation of a line different from, yet parallel to $( x, y, z ) = (1, 1, -1) + t(1, -2, -1)$

Tags: geometry, 3d

> Line $L_2$ is $( x, y, z ) = (1, 1, -1) + t(1, -2, -1)$
>
> Find the parametric equation of a line $L_4$ which is different from, yet parallel to, the line $L_2$ given above.

Where I am at so far:

All I know is that two lines in three dimensions are parallel if the direction vectors of both lines are scalar multiples of each other. So I know $L_4$'s direction vector is $(1, -2, -1)$. But that's all I got.

Comment: To complete your parametric definition of $L_4$ you need one point on the line $L_4$.  But how can you choose that point so that $L_4$ will not be the same line as $L_2$?

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure. I've thought about it but nothing is coming to mind.

Comment: You have to understand what $( x, y, z ) = (1, 1, -1) + t(1, -2, -1)$ means.

Comment: It's the vector equation of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Convince yourself that $(0,0,0)$ is not a point on $L_2$.

Then

$$L_4:  \quad ( x, y, z ) = (0, 0, 0) + t(1, -2, -1)$$

will do the job.

Comment: So all I need to do is just find any old point that doesn't lie on $L_2$ and use that for the vector equation of $L_4$? Because that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation 
$$( x, y, z ) = (1, 1, -1) + t(1, -2, -1)$$
the $(1, 1, -1)$ is a point on the line (for $t=0$) and the $(1, -2, -1)$ is a vector, that gives the direction of the line. Therefore parallel lines are
$$( x, y, z ) = (\alpha, \beta, \gamma) + t(1, -2, -1)$$
and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in \mathbb{R}$.